# Date process Different

Tags: mysql

I have table `JobOrder` with 5 columns: (`jo_no`, `jo_type`, `jo_release`, `jo_date`, `jo_livedate`)

Using the MySQL query below, I am counting the `jo_type`:

```
select jo_no, jo_date, jo_livedate, count(*) from joborder
where jo_no='1232';
```

output:

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| jo_no | jo_date   | jo_livedate | count(*) | 
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 1232  | 01-dec-14 | 05-dec-14   | 5        |
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

I want to output the difference of `jo_date` and `jo_livedate`. If the difference is 5 days I need to generate 5 records as below ...

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| jo_no | date      | count(*)**  | 
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1232  | 01-dec-14 | 5           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1232  | 02-dec-14 | 5           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1232  | 03-dec-14 | 5           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1232  | 04-dec-14 | 5           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1232  | 05-dec-14 | 5           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want to generate the extra dates in between `jo_date` and `jo_livedate`. What do you need to do this for? I smell [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/254929).

Comment: This for generating the report proposes. Please let me know the solution.